# Apply a javascript function to a dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an autocomplete function, this works for the already created input field with id="field10". However when I dynamically create new input fields the function does not work on them. I have even specified what the input field names will be in advance of the fields being created. I have checked that the created field ids are correct, what am I doing wrong? Below is the script used to generate the new input fields.

```
        //Add Input Fields
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var max_fields = 10; //Maximum allowed input fields 
            var wrapper    = $(".array_wrap"); //Input fields wrapper
            var add_button = $(".add_fields"); //Add button class or ID
            var x = 1; //Initial input field is set to 1

         //When user click on add input button
         $(add_button).click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
         //Check maximum allowed input fields
                if(x < max_fields){ 
                    x++; //input field increment
         //add input field
                    var inputA = document.createElement('a');
                    $(inputA).attr("href", "javascript:void(0);");
                    $(inputA).attr("class","remove_field")
                    inputA.innerText ="Remove";
                    var inputName = document.createElement('input');
                    $(inputName).attr('id','field10' + x);
                    $(inputName).attr('type','text');
                    $(inputName).attr('name','input_array_name[]');

                    $(inputName).attr('placeholder','Subject');
                    $(inputName).appendTo($(wrapper));
                    $(inputA).appendTo($(wrapper));
                }
            });

//
These are the values I have passed to the function...
        autocomplete(document.getElementById("field10"), countries);
        autocomplete(document.getElementById("field101"), countries);
        autocomplete(document.getElementById("field102"), countries);
        autocomplete(document.getElementById("field103"), countries);
        autocomplete(document.getElementById("field104"), countries);
        autocomplete(document.getElementById("field105"), countries);
        autocomplete(document.getElementById("field106"), countries);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that these are the correct ids? 
Else i think it's worth to work with classes instead of Ids, beacause you have to loop on an array of element having that class name it's even easier to be dynamic.